# fragment does not reflect changes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create an application in which my `Fragment` contains one `listview` which is populated from a database, and when one of the item is clicked, a new activity starts.

In this new activity, I update the database, and then come back to the first `Fragment` (by pressing back button).

What happens next is that the `ListView` in the first `Fragment` does not take the changes I made in the second `Activity` into account.

And strange thing is that when I start the application again, the `Fragment` shows the updated list.

How can I automatically update the `ListView` when making changes to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the *onResume( )* method in your Fragment, so you can told the Adapter that the Dataset has changed.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Dataset has changed, notify adapter !
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```